# Javascript For don´t complete array loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach, array.prototype.map

I'm trying build a loop with an array of 12 positions, wrapping 5 items with  and insert another code after this interval, but for some reason the loop only goes up to 10.
Why the loop stops at tenth position only when the array has 11 or 12 positions?
Someone can explain me the reason about it?

```
let x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
x.map(_=> {
    console.log("<div>");
    x.splice(0,5).map((y,k)=>
        console.log('item: ' + y)
    )
    console.log("</div>");
    console.log('interval of 5 text');
});

x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
for(i=0; i < x.length; i++){
    let x2 = x.splice(0,5);
    console.log("<div>");
    for(j=0; j < x2.length; j++){
        console.log('item: ' + x2[j]);
    }
    console.log("</div>");
    console.log('interval of 5');
}
```

Comment: altering an array in the loop while it is looped is never a good idea

Comment: Why not if theoretically i have control over it?
Anyway, I just want to understand why the loop stops at tenth position only when the array has 11 or 12 positions?

Comment: Because you alter the array within the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question why.

Let me clear that loop a bit and just keep the `splice` method (since it is the thing that mutates your array) and log the length of the array `x` to console in each iteration.

```js
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
for(var i=0; i < x.length; i++){
    let x2 = x.splice(0,5);
    console.log(x.length);
}
```

And let's see what happens.

```
loop execution:
------------------------------ 
i  |  x.length  |  i < x.length
------------------------------
0  |     12     |     true
1  |     7      |     true
2  |     2      |     false
```

that is why your loop ends after the second iteration (which is the 10th position since you are processing 5 positions in a single iteration).

---

One way to have a code which performs that mentioned logic and leaves the array clear afterwards would be this.

Create a function that does the following:

- take the array and size of the group
- create copy of that array
- get the right number of iterations
- perform your logic
- return (empty array) and reassign the old array

To get the correct number of iterations, divide length of the array by the size of group and round it up.

```js
let x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];

function customArrayLoop(arr, toTake) {
  const arrCopy = [...arr];
  const loopMax = Math.ceil(x.length / toTake);

  for (let i = 0; i < loopMax; i++) {
    let x2 = arrCopy.splice(0,5);
    console.log("<div>");
    for(let j=0; j < x2.length; j++){
      console.log('item: ' + x2[j]);
    }
    console.log("</div>");
    console.log('interval of 5');
  }

  return arrCopy;
}

x = customArrayLoop(x, 5);
console.log(x);
```

While still not the best you can get (since you want to keep that internal logic of the loop), it is much safer solution.

Comment: Thanks! I probally will use while(x.length) instead for or map.

Comment: @ThiagoMachado Yes changing that loop to `while(x.length > 0)` will indeed work in this case, but it is definitely the wrong way to go. What exactly are trying to achieve? (I am sure there is a better solution)

Comment: I want to run the entire array, like i wrote in the post and ensure that the array will be cleaned at the end.

Comment: Thanks! That clarified me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are altering your original array while iterating:

```
let x2 = x.splice(0,5); // should be avoided.
```

With each alteration the length of your array also decreases.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Array.slice(...)** instead **Array.splice(...)**

```
let x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

After a = **x.splice(0,5)** =>
 x => [5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
 a => [0,1,2,3,4]

After a = **x.slice(0,5)** =>
 x => [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
 a => [0,1,2,3,4]
```

Since you use ( ... i < x.length ... ) condition, after two **splice** operation you reach the end of the array. (with loop you get the same case)